# Efficently Computing the Inverse Affine Transform

Tags: transformation

Given a single affine transformation in 3D (i.e., TRS transforms) that is
represented by a translation vector (t), quaternion (r) and scaling vector (s).

Is there some way of efficiently computing the inverse transform, while
maintaining the same representation?

I initially thought that this was a simple as inverting each component, but a
simple test with the resulting 4x4 matrices for these transforms clearly shows
that this is incorrect. E.g., the transform:

```
A  := ({t=(10, 1, 0), r=(0.97, 0.26, 0, 0), s=(5, 5, 5)}
B  := inv(A)       // {t=(-10, -1, 0), r=(0.97, -0.26, 0, 0), s=(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)}
ma := A.to_mat4()  // { { 5 0 0 10 } { 0 4.3 -2.5 1 } { 0 2.5 4.3 0 } { 0 0 0 1 } }
mb := B.to_mat4()  // { { 0.2 0 0 -10 } { 0 0.17 0.1 -1 } { 0 -0.1 0.17 -0 } { 0 0 0 1 } }
i  := ma * mb      // { { 1 0 0 -40 } { 0 1 0 -3.33013 } { 0 0 1 -2.5 } { 0 0 0 1 } }
                   // Clearly not the identity matrix
```

Is this actually possible to do in some way? If not, are there some
circumstances under which this can be done?

Comment: remember the matrix inversion rule: `inv(A*B) = inv(B)*inv(A)`

Comment: How does that apply to this case? I'm not actually inverting any matrices, in fact, that's what I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you have the transform split into components you apply them one at a time to an object:

```
o1 = object.scale(trs.scale);
o2 = o1.rotate(trs.quaternion);
o3 = o2.translate(trs.translate);
```

Or in other' words the final equivalent transformation matrix for this order is `M = Trans*Rot*Scale`

However the inversion rule requires that you swap the operands of the multiply when you invert it

```
inv(M) = inv(Trans*Rot*Scale) = inv(Scale)*inv(Rot)*inv(Trans)
```

Which is the wrong order

Uniform scale and rotate will be commutative with each other so that is not an issue.

In the end you need to find a translation such that `T_result*inv(Rot)*inv(Scale) == inv(Scale)*inv(Rot)*inv(Trans)`

Some basic matrix multiplications on both sides gives me:

```
T_result*inv(Rot)*inv(Scale)*Scale  == inv(Scale)*inv(Rot)*inv(Trans)*Scale
T_result*inv(Rot)*Rot               == inv(Scale)*inv(Rot)*inv(Trans)*Scale*Rot
T_result                            == inv(Scale)*inv(Rot)*inv(Trans)*Scale*Rot
```

Comment: Thanks! This mostly solved my issues, however I should note that the `T_result` matrix wouldn't actually be a pure translation if handled in this way, and hence the transform can't be represented the same way as the input (t=vec3, r=quat, s=vec3). In the end, it seems simpler to add a boolean to this representation to flip the multiplication order when necessary, or as I did, simply having a separate function to generate the inverse (`.to_inv_mat4()`).